# Trying to create a constructor that will initialize 'number' with a number given in an argument and set the length

Tags: java, string, constructor, biginteger

Trying to create a constructor in java that will initialize 'number' with the number given in an argument and set the length.

I set an integer 'l' to number.length and set the length = l

```
public BigInteger(String num){
        int l = number.length;
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)number[i] = num[i];
        length = l;

    }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char

    at BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:16)
    at BigInteger.main(BigInteger.java:322)
```

Comment: What is the type of number?

Comment: You cannot access a letter in a `String` with the `[]` notation in Java. Is `number` a `char[]`? If so, you want to do `number[i] = num.charAt(i)`.

Comment: Warning! The JDK also includes a `BigInteger` class.  Using the names of JDK classes for your own classes can potentially lead of all sorts of interesting (i.e., confusing) conflict-of-interest situations.  Just be careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your cod, you are using `num[i]`. While `num` is not an `array` type. It is of type `String`.
Looks like `number` is of type `char[]`. So your code should be like:

```
public BigInteger(String num){
        int l = number.length;
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++) {
          //Change is here
          number[i] = num.charAt(i);
        }   
        length = l;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks so much!! I had another instance of that in my code as well and changing it as you said made it right.